# What anime is this female anime figure in blue uniform from?

Tags: merchandise

I recently bought a Hideyoshi Kinoshita figure on ebay, when it arrived I noticed that the seller had included a small figure of a loli girl in a blue uniform with yellow ball looking badges on it, white shoes red hair with a long cowlick and sword with a cat charm on the handle. Can anyone tell me where she is from? It's been driving me nuts for days! it would be much appreciated. [image]

Comment: You could always try and ask the seller ^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The female character in the above picture is [Kurogane Hayate](http://hayatexblade.wikia.com/wiki/Kurogane_Hayate) from [Hayate x Blade](http://myanimelist.net/manga/4145/Hayate_x_Blade).

> [image]
>
> ```
>                    Kurogane Hayate's appearance in the Manga
> ```

The Manga currently does not have an anime adaptation. You can find the figurine [here](https://myanimeshelf.com/figures/308540_Dengeki_Daioh_Collection:_Kurogane_Hayate).